# Accessing local router (Linksys EA7500) via hostname instead of IP address?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

We recently purchased a new router—a [Linksys EA7500](http://www.linksys.com/us/p/P-EA7500/)—and it supports USB storage sharing via Samba. I’m setting up some local backups on devices in our home, and instead of setting it up to hit `smb://192.18.1.1/backup_share/`, I would prefer `smb://router/backup_share`, as it’s both easier to type and remember.

Further, if the subnet changes to `192.168.5.x` to avoid any conflicts with my work VPN (which changes frequently), it semi-future-proofs against that too.

What's neat is that the router seems to come with its own (editable) hostname. But it only seems to be half-recognized?

```
craig@[~] host Linksys02034
Linksys02034 has address 192.168.1.1
craig@[~] ping Linksys02034
ping: cannot resolve Linksys02034: Unknown host
```

What would cause `host` to find the IP, but not other tools like `ping` or my web browser? The Linksys EA7500 does *seem* to support having a hostname accessible on the network:

[image: Local Network Router Settings]

Comment: After you define the hostname in your /etc/hosts file does it work?

Comment: Is it the DNS server for your network?